# Integrating ASP.NET MVC with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver4, access-token, .net-framework-version

Currently I am trying to use Identity Server 4 to authenticate the user. Basically I have already setup the Identity Server 4 and tested it with a .NET Core project.

But now when it redirects back from the identity server to the redirected URL, I am unable to retrieve the access token.

In .NET Core, it can be accessed via  `HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync()`, `httpcontext.GetTokenAsync()`. How should I do it in .NET framework?

Thanks :)

Comment: In order to read the token it needs to be persisted first. Assuming an mvc application, did you include this line in AddOpenIdConnect?: `options.SaveTokens = true;`. Check [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/3_aspnetcore_and_apis.html?highlight=gettokenasync#modifying-the-mvc-client) for the documentation. If you scroll down: `var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");` (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication namespace).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am working on .Net Framework not .Net Core... In the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions, there is no SaveToken option and same goes to GetTokenAsync.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. The naming can be quite confusing. You should look at IdentityServer3 packages because those are compatible with .net45 and should be compatible with IdentityServer4 as well. Perhaps this [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/MVC%20Authentication/EmbeddedMvc/Controllers/CallApiController.cs#L24) is useful for you.